# Using PostCSS Global Data with Next.js

Tags: next.js, postcss

I'm using PostCSS with [postcss-preset-env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env) (now part of [postcss-plugins monorepo](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins)) and [postcss-custom-media](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugins/postcss-custom-media) to be able to declare my global breakpoints once and have them available to use in CSS Modules throughout my project. [Modular CSS processing](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugins/postcss-custom-media#modular-css-processing) is specifically mentioned in the docs for `postcss-custom-media` where it recommends using
[postcss-global-data](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugins/postcss-global-data) to allow for defining variables once and have them available during processing of CSS Modules.

I've created a [custom PostCSS config for my Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/post-css#customizing-plugins) project and followed [the instructions for using `postcss-global-data` with Next.js](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/blob/main/plugins/postcss-global-data/INSTALL.md#nextjs) but so far I've been unable to get it working in my CSS Modules.

In `src/styles/tokens.css` I define my breakpoints (I've tried both inside and outside of `:root{}`):

```css
/* Breakpoints */
@custom-media --screen-sm (width >= 576px);
@custom-media --screen-md (width >= 768px);
@custom-media --screen-lg (width >= 1200px);
```

I create a custom PostCSS config for use with Next.js. The contents of `postcss.config.js` is:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
        [
            'postcss-preset-env',
            {
                autoprefixer: {
                    flexbox: 'no-2009',
                },
                stage: 3,
                features: {
                    'custom-media-queries': true,
                    // CSS variables aren't compiled because it's not safe.
                    'custom-properties': false,
                    'nesting-rules': true,
                },
            },
        ],
        [
            '@csstools/postcss-global-data',
            {
                files: ['src/styles/tokens.css'],
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

And inside one of my CSS Modules I try the following:

```css
.heroSearchBox {
    width: 100%;

    @media (--screen-md) {
        max-width: 400px;
    }
}
```

But this has no effect.

I can confirm that:

1. The rest of my custom `postcss.config.css` is working fine
2. If I copy my custom breakpoints into my CSS Module css file that also works. E.g

```css
/* Breakpoints */
@custom-media --screen-sm (width >= 576px);
@custom-media --screen-md (width >= 768px);
@custom-media --screen-lg (width >= 1200px);

.heroSearchBox {
    width: 100%;

    @media (--screen-md) {
        max-width: 400px;
    }
}
```

However, that would obviously lead to a lot of duplications as would a css import which I'm looking to avoid and the reason that `postcss-global-data` is recommended.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong or how I may get this working?

Answer (score 2):

**Resolved.** This was due to the order of configuration items in my `postcss.config.js` file. `postcss-global-data` needs to come before the `postcss-preset-env`:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
        [
            '@csstools/postcss-global-data',
            {
                files: ['src/styles/media-queries.css'],
            },
        ],
        [
            'postcss-preset-env',
            {
                autoprefixer: {
                    flexbox: 'no-2009',
                },
                stage: 3,
                features: {
                    'custom-media-queries': true,
                    // CSS variables aren't compiled because it's not safe.
                    'custom-properties': false,
                    'nesting-rules': true,
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```